# Ruby on Rails and angularJS: Can someone explain the usage and syntax pls

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, syntax

```js
angular.module('MyModule').controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'MyService', 'MyOtherService', function ($scope, $timeout, MyService, MyOtherService) {
 <!-- some code -->
}])
```

I am new to ROR framework and am trying to figure out what this code snippet is trying to do. Also how does angular service works. Is there a way access the service in another module different from the module it is defined in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code is purely `angularjs`.. there is nothing `RoR` about it..
I'll describe the word by word.

1. `angular` this is a reference to the global `angular` object.
2. `.module` call gets/initiates a component of your `application` you might notice this in your html/erb/haml file as an attribute (`ng-app`) of a tag. here its `getting` the module named `MyModule`.
3. `.controller` call creates/initiates a controller on the component 'MyModule', for a beginner level it requires 2 arguments, first is the name of the `controller` (`MyController` in your case) by which it'll be address. second is the `controller` `function`.
4. The `array` you see as the second argument might be a bit tricky, Angular uses it for dependency injection into the `controller` function, the first `n-1` elements are the name of the components like services, factories.. etc. you'd like to use inside the controller. these are then passed as arguments inside your controller function.

Comment: Is there a way access the service in another module different from the module it is defined in?

Comment: well that's rather a tricky question.. `dependency` injection is th way to do it..

Comment: @Dreamer if you could tell me a use case I might be able to help you better.

Comment: I have two modules, say, Mod1 and Mod2. Mod2 has controller2, service2 defined in it. Now I want to use service2 in Mod1. I have tried by directly injecting the service into Mod1's controller. However its breaking the page in which Mod1's controller is being used.

Comment: @Dreamer, yes you can do it rather easily.. look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/Typ1VrA3yqv6eILkW6Va?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

This snippet is pure AngularJS code.

```
angular.module('MyModule')
```

this part creates module.

(You can read about modules here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

```
controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'MyService', 'MyOtherService', function
```

this part creates controller.

(About controllers: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

and injects in it services: '$scope', '$timeout', 'MyService', 'MyOtherService'

(About Dependecy injection: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: Is there a way access the service in another module different from the module it is defined in?

Comment: If service declared in module like this:
angular.module("TestModule").factory("SomeService", function(){});

Then you can use it in another module like this:
    angular.module("AnotherModule",["TestModule"]).controller("MyController",["SomeService",function(someService){});

Comment: It was declared as: angular.module("TestModule").service("SomeService", function(){}))